# Triggering a second refresh when stored procedure doesn't throw data on the first time

Tags: jquery, sql-server, stored-procedures, laravel-4

I using laravel 4.1. The page data is fetched throw a stored procedure call.
The stored procedure requires double page refresh to fetch data when a new user or element is introduced to the stored procedure. The data will not be available for all users. For some it will be empty and for some may not. And the latter is the one that takes two calls to load data when the user is new.
I thought of triggering the second call with jquery refresh. I like to know if there's any best solutions to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making 2 HTTP calls in jQuery is an option.
However I still recommend you to make sure that you get the correct results already during the first call. There must be a way in Controller to get the correct results without calling it twice.